# Water level indicator using CMOS inverter

Tags: mosfet, circuit-design, nmos, pmos, orcad

I want to build the below circuit. The circuit has three levels to indicate water. low->o/p LED. Medium->O/P LED. High->O/P LED + Buzzer. Each level has two types of MOSFET; they work as CMOS inverters.
What to use for the N-mos and P-mos? If you could give me names; I want something that I can simulate on OrCAD and build in real life. Also, I am not sure about the high level. Should I connect the other terminal of the source (9v) to the tank or not (the black wire)?

[image]

Comment: Did you mean CMOS?

Comment: There seem to be a lot of people asking about this lately - is this for a school assignment?

Comment: @PeterBennett I believe yes.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Yes, thank you I meant "CMOS".

Comment: Instead of Building Cmos inverters, why not use an CD4069 IC that has six inverters in it. Is your water perfectly clean so that it is an insulator causing your circuit to do nothing? Your circuit needs salt or dirty water that conducts.  What logic level are the gates if there is no water? They need pullup resistors to make them produce a high logic level.

Comment: @Audioguru My project should contain MOSFETs. That's why my choices are limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously stated by previous answers, I also think there are a couple of errors on your circuit, mainly the fact that you don't consider the conductance of water, thus the transistors may not saturate; this conductance better be measured on practice for the 3 water levels you are searching for.

I would like to share a simple circuit, I think a simple N-channel mosfet should be enough:

[image]

In this circuit, let `Rw` be the resistance of a specific water level, resistors `R1 R2` are part of the design and the load may be a LED or LED/BUZZER. This circuit should be easy to simulate.

As part of your homework and design, you should ask yourself: should `R2` be lower or higher than `Rw`? What if I add a resistor such that `Rw = Rw' + R3`? What should be the ratio between `R1` and `Rgs` to saturate the transistor?

These questions are a bit extensive and depend on your electronic device and application.

I really hope this helps and good luck.

Answer (score 1):

This won't actually work.

When the water reaches each electrode, the voltage will be pulled low, the corresponding inverter will be high and its LED will illuminate.

But when the water has *not* reached it, the inverter's input will be floating and so it voltage will be unpredictable. It will also be unpredictable in a simulation.

Since this is probably a homework assignment, I won't give a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

- you don’t need inverters. Only one FET is sufficient.

In your diagram you could dispense with the n-FETs.

- add weak pull-ups to your inputs

The FET gates need some kind of pull-up when there is no water present. However, this raises an issue: how resistive is your water, and how big/far apart are your electrodes that sense it? You’ll need to know that to adjust the pull-up value; it may take some experimentation.